# Use of mixed type accepted on single typed parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript1.7

Given the following [Code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F%2F%20This%20is%20meant%20to%20be%20a%20collection%20of%20compare%20functions%0D%0Aconst%20compareFn%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20numberAsc%3A%20function%20(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%7B%20return%20a%20-%20b%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20numberDesc%3A%20function%20(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%7B%20return%20b%20-%20a%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20numberDesc%20only%20accepts%20numbers%2C%20but%20sort%20will%20also%20aplly%20the%20string%20%22nope%22%0D%0A%5B2%2C%201%2C%20%22nope%22%5D.sort(compareFn.numberDesc)%3B) in TypeScript:

```
const compareFn = {
    numberAsc: function (a: number, b: number) { return a - b },
    numberDesc: function (a: number, b: number) { return b - a },
};

[2, 1, "nope"].sort(compareFn.numberDesc);
```

[image]

My function `numberDesc` is only accepting attributes of type `number`. However `sort` will apply both `number` and `string` to it. That's wrong, but accepted by TypeScript.

My guess is that TypeScript is expecting for the `sort()` function a compareFn that accepts number or string, but not strictly both. However in my opinion it should only allow a function that is accepting both number and string.

Is this a "Bug" or does TypeScript intend to behave like that?
But most importantly: can I make it work? Given an array is should only accept compatible sort-functions.

---

Note that it's working fine here:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is what you have:

```
type Foo = (a:number,b:number)=>number;
type Bar = (a:number|string,b:number|string)=>number|string;

let foo:Foo;
let bar:Bar;
bar = foo; // Why is this valid!
```

Its valid because *the following is valid* :

```
let x:number;
let y:number|string;
y = x; // Valid for obvious reasons
```

And when checking function compatibility the parameter compatibility is checked in *both directions*.

More on that here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Type%20Compatibility.md#comparing-two-functions

> Is this a "Bug" or does TypeScript intend to behave like that?

Intended to behave like that.

> But most importantly: can I make it work? Given an array is should only accept compatible sort-functions.

No. As explained the semantics of *compatible* function in TypeScript allow bivariance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer basarat. While this is a good answer,  I updated my question to be more direct on my problem. I hope that its now clear why I think, that it shouldn't be accepted. Do you possibly have a solution how I can work around this?

Comment: I've quoted portions of your updated question and answered them explicitly 

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive that I understand your question but I hope this helps. You need the array to only accept numbers. Your function returns a number so no problem there.

```
const compareFn = {
    numberAsc: function (a: number, b: number) { return a - b },
    numberDesc: function (a: number, b: number) { return b - a },
};

console.log([2, 1, "nope"].sort(compareFn.numberDesc));
console.log([2, 1, "nope"].sort(compareFn.numberAsc));
var numberArray = new Array<number>();
numberArray.push(2, 1);
numberArray.push(3, 4, "nope"); // kaboom
console.log(numberArray.sort(compareFn.numberDesc));
console.log(numberArray.sort(compareFn.numberAsc));
numberArray.push("nope"); // kaboom
```

Of course, the JavaScript that gets generated has no problem with any of this but tsc will complain.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Joel. I clarified my question. I want it to do it the other way - given an array is should only accept compatible sort-functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me explain my answer here even though basarat already gave a perfect one. May be it helps someone to make things more clear.

TypeScript's type checking system is **not a sound** system, meaning it allows operations that are not known to be safe at compile time. Your example is of this kind.
Type inference of your array literal makes TypeScript expect a compare function with this signature

```js
(a: number | string, b: number | string) => number
```

This is what I would have expected, because your array is of type

```js
Array<number | string>
```

Therefore I would like to rephrase your question "is this a bug?" to "why is numberDesc considered compatible with this signature?"

The answer has been given by basarat.

Coming from a Java background, I can understand your desire to have a more strict type checking like in Java, but I guess you can't get it here.